How to upgrade to Azure.Storage.Common from Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage?
I have implemented the functionality to serve videos from Azure blob storage in an MVC application using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage. The controller code below works and shows the basic functionality for getting a URL to serve. This is used in conjunction with the Videos.cshtml view shown underneath.
Whilst this works, the WindowsAzure.Storage is now deprecated and Microsoft recommend upgrading to Azure.Storage.Common. However, this package does not seem to have the same methods and I cannot find a good reference for how to migrate from Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage to Azure.Storage.Common.
Could anyone point me in the direction of a good reference / tutorial for how to convert the code below? Even better, if someone could show explicitly how to convert this code, it would be greatly appreciated!
The controller code
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Mvc;

/*
 * Requires installing WindowsAzure.Storage via Nuget manager
 * Note deprecated! - recommended to use Azure.Storage.Common
 * Additional Details:
 * Please note, this package is obsolete as of 3/31/2023 and is no longer maintained or monitored. 
 * Microsoft encourages you to upgrade to the replacement package, Azure.Storage.Common, to 
 * continue receiving updates. Refer to our deprecation policy 
 * (https://aka.ms/azsdk/support-policies) for more details.
 */
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;


namespace MyPlatform.Controllers
{

    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public class MyController : Controller
    {
        
        /// <summary>
        /// Test page for streaming training videos.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>View of the Videos page.</returns>
        public ActionResult Videos()
        {
            // Get strings from Web.config file
            string accountName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Storage:AccountName"];
            string keyValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Storage:KeyValue"];
            string containerName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Storage:ContainerName"];
            string videoName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Storage:VideoName"];

            var credentials = new StorageCredentials(accountName, keyValue);
            var account = new CloudStorageAccount(credentials, true); // true for using HTTPS
            var container = account.CreateCloudBlobClient().GetContainerReference(containerName);
            var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(videoName);

            // Need URL to stream video. To get URL, need to set up permissions
            var sharedAccessSig = blob.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
            {
                Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read,
                SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1)
            });

            string videoUrl = string.Format("{0}{1}", blob.Uri, sharedAccessSig);

            ViewData["Video"] = videoUrl; 

            return View();
        }


    }
}

The view code
The code above is used in conjunction with the view

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Videos";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MyLayout.cshtml";

    var videoUrl = (string)ViewData["Video"];
 
}

<h2>Videos</h2>

<p>Test page for streaming videos.</p>

<video controls controlslist="nodownload" disablepictureinpicture>
    <source src=@videoUrl type="video/mp4">
</video>



FYI, simply serving a video from Blob storage does not constitute "streaming" as video. "Streaming" generally refers to the (re)broadcast of a still-live video source (e.g. like Twitch).

@Dai Thanks - I have edited the terminology accordingly.

Relevant examples are on https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/Azure.Storage.Common_12.20.1/sdk/storage/Azure.Storage.Blobs/README.md#Examples - have you not seen that page?


Azure.Storage.Common isn't what you want - you want Azure.Storage.Blobs.

(Azure.Storage.Blobs itself lists Azure.Storage.Common as a dependency)


Using Primary/Secondary Storage Account Keys is still supported, but their use isn't encouraged.

Instead, if (and when) your application is running within an Azure App Service or Azure VM, make use of a Managed Identity to access other Azure resources in your Subscription without needing any passwords/keys/codes/secrets at all.




API changes:

StorageSharedKeyCredential replaces StorageCredentials.
BlobServiceClient replaces CloudStorageAccount.
BlobContainerClient replaces CloudBlobContainer.
BlobClient replaces CloudBlob; while its subclasses (CloudBlockBlob, CloudPageBlob, and CloudAppendBlob) are replaced by types in Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.
To generate a SAS URI for a Blob, use BlobSasBuilder.

You no-longer need to have a BlobClient to generate a SAS for a Blob.
Note that Storage-Account-Key-based SAS access is no-longer encouraged. Microsoft recommends using User delegation SAS instead (which I'm unfamiliar with, I'll admit).



Like so:
Old:
StorageCredentials  credentials = new StorageCredentials(accountName, keyValue);
CloudStorageAccount account     = new CloudStorageAccount(credentials, true);

CloudBlobContainer  container   = account.CreateCloudBlobClient().GetContainerReference(containerName);
CloudBlockBlob      blob        = container.GetBlockBlobReference(videoName);

String sharedAccessSig = blob.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
{
    Permissions            = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read,
    SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1)
});

String videoUrl = string.Format("{0}{1}", blob.Uri, sharedAccessSig);

New:
using Azure.Storage;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Sas; // For `BlobSasBuilder`

// ...

StorageSharedKeyCredential sharedKeyCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName, accountKey);

BlobServiceClient svcClient = new BlobServiceClient(
    serviceUri: new Uri("https://" + accountName + ".blob.core.windows.net"),
    credential: sharedKeyCredential
);

BlobContainerClient container = svcClient.GetBlobContainerClient(blobContainerName: containerName);
BlobClient blob = container.GetBlobClient(blobName: videoName);

BlobSasBuilder bsb = new BlobSasBuilder(
    permissions: BlobSasPermissions.Read,
    expiresOn  : DateTimeOffset.Now.AddHours(1)
)
{
    BlobContainerName = containerName,
    BlobName          = videoName
};

BlobSasQueryParameters sasQueryParameters = bsb.ToSasQueryParameters(sharedKeyCredential);

UriBuilder ub = new UriBuilder()
{
    Scheme = "https",
    Host   = accountName + ".blob.core.windows.net",
    Path   = containerName + "/" + videoName,
    Query  = sasQueryParameters.ToString()
};

Uri videoUri = ub.Uri;

I'll admit I'm surprised at the extra legwork required to use BlobSasBuilder (with BlobSasQueryParameters and UriBuilder). I hope/assume there's a shortcut to this, but I haven't looked deeper.

